# Positive integer solutions to $3x^4-3x^2+1=y^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I need to solve
$$3x^4-3x^2+1=y^2$$
over the positive integers.

---

I've tried setting $x^2=t$ and considering the discriminant. I've tried rewriting into $3(2x^2-1)^2+1=(2y)^2$. I've tried substituting $x=3a\pm 1$. The problem would be easy by bounding if the leading coefficient is a perfect square.

Comment: Note: $y $ is even and $y=3m\pm1$ for some $m\in\mathbb {Z}^+$.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3886637/show-that-3n43n21-is-never-a-perfect-square?noredirect=1&lq=1) how to write it as elliptic curve (with $-3x^2$ instead of $3x^2$).

Comment: $y$ is always odd regardless of $x$

Comment: Also [Art of Problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h127208p722051) has several pages with solutions. Here the notation is $3p^4-3p^2+1=q^2$. Again [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h22074p142033) with $3q^4-3q^2+1=t^2$.